# String data flow with encoding and decoding from browser to mysql database and vice versa

Tags: string, character-encoding

User inserts a string in a html form input on browser. This string is saved in database. How this string is encoded and decoded at each stage based on character encoding?

Flow as per technology stack used: browser --> ajax post --> spring mvc -->hibernate -->mysql db

Comment: Q: What makes you think there's *any* implicit encoding/decoding being done?

Comment: We can specify a character encoding on MySQL. Suppose if i specify latin. So how does encoding and decoding happen at that layer. Html forms can submit the data with application/x-www-form-urlencoded,does spring mvc decodes the values before sumitting them to java controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expect that the browser post is an URL encoded UTF-8.  Within the Java JVM, the string uses UTF-16, therefore roughly doubling the size taken if it is English text.  Hibernate is part of that and it does not really care about the encoding, although it does pass around with connection strings as described next (`hibernate.connection.url` property).

The UTF-16 string is then translated by the JDBC driver which, in case of MySQL, will use the `characterEncoding` property inside the connection string.  It helps if this matches the encoding of the database declared in `CREATE DATABASE` statement, avoiding another re-encoding.

Finally, "latin" is not a name of a specific character set or encoding.  You probably mean ISO 8859-1, also known as Latin-1.  This is not a good choice for a web server as it will not be able to represent most non-English strings.  You should use UTF-8 in the database and in the connection string, ending up with UTF-8 -> UTF-16 -> UTF-8 which is a safe and reasonably efficient sequence (not counting any encoding that might be happening in the browser itself).

If you decide to alter the database to use UTF-8, be careful about changing the encoding at table level, too.  Each table may use its own encoding and it does not change automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer. I understand your reason for not using latin-1. But suppose db has character encoding latin1. In this case JDBC driver will convert the Java UTF-16 character into latin-1 encoding and pass on to database. Does that mean the encoding specified on hibernate connection url should be same as character encoding defined on MySQL server?

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi - The JDBC driver will usually be able to autodetect the encoding from the database.  If you want to override this autodetection in connection string, then yes, I would expect that you would try to match the encoding used by the database server to minimize some kind of data loss.  For example, if the database uses a different encoding than relevant tables in it, you might want to force the encoding that matches the tables.